# ceate array of image in UIscrollview?

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiview

I want to create array of image instead of one image in below code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
    {
        UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(550, 800);
        NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"page-1.jpg" ];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
        [scrollView addSubview:imageView];
        imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
        [imageView release];
        scrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
        [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
        [scrollView release];
        [super viewDidLoad];
    }
```

how i create it? and deploy another functionality of scroll view.

Comment: can you elaborate more on this ? What exactly are you looking for ?

Comment: do you want to add images dynamically in scroll view? If yes, do you want to have images come horizontally or vertically? Do you want to swipe images?

Comment: in above now only one image is used now i want to create array of images. which scroll both side. and add zoom by pinch or tap  event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed your code a bit to add 10 images, instead of 1. Is this what you want?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{

    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];

    int numberOfImages = 10;
    CGFloat currentX = 0.0f;

    for (int i=1; i <= numberOfImages; i++) {

        // create image
        NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"page-%d.jpg", i];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

        // put image on correct position
        CGRect rect = imageView.frame;
        rect.origin.x = currentX;
        imageView.frame = rect;

        // update currentX
        currentX += imageView.frame.size.width;

        [scrollView addSubview:imageView];
        [imageView release];
    }

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(currentX, 800);

    scrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
    [scrollView release];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: currentX is the position inside the scrollView where the image will appear. The enable page scrolling, set scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;

Comment: Thanks for help .can u tell me how implement zooming functionality with images in above code?or when tap on image then upload same bigger image from url or webservice.